# Is query string in https url encrypted

Tags: vb6, https, query-string

I want to use an sms gateway company's https api.

This involves sending confidential information in the query string part of the url.

I am using the ms internet transfer control's execute method.

Will this control encrypt the query string before sending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it all gets sent encrypted.  I'd probably avoid that old control though since we have other options today that are more flexible.

Comment: Great, thank you. This project is vb6, are there convenent alternatives to the inet control available for vb6

Comment: VB6's AsyncRead method can do GET requests.  There are very few systems that won't have a version of MSXML installed (which offers XmlHttpRequest objects), and from Win2K onward we have the WinHttpRequest object preinstalled.  The old WinInet control dates back to early Win9x limitations, VB prior to 6.0, etc. and today offers little but its limited FTP capabilities to recommend it.

Comment: @BobRiemersma Are you sure? AFAIK the GET query string is visible for HTTPS. I must admit not having actually looked with a packet sniffer recently, but I thought you needed to POST variables to get encryption with HTTPS.

Comment: Yes i am sure. You can see a discussion of this and some paranoid exceptions at http://blog.httpwatch.com/2009/02/20/how-secure-are-query-strings-over-https/